# Simplesaml Auth error when clearing cache

Tags: docker, drupal, simplesamlphp, drush

I'm doing a local install of a Drupal 8 site and when I try to clear the cache with Drush, I get this error:
[image]

Is anyone familiar with this?  I can't find anything relevant with a Google search.  Thank you in advance for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to install the library with composer. If you did it, run the next code:

```
composer update
```

You can find more information in the next link

https://simplesamlphp.org/modules

Comment: Do you score negatively the answer without information?